# object doesn't support this property or method CheckBox ControlFormat.Value =1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying check the ChechBox, but comes Object doesn't support this property or method, I don't know why.
 Here is the standard code:

```
Sub Check_Method1(cbbln As Boolean)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wst As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

  If cbbln = True Then
    'Check the checkbox
    wb.wst.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = 1
  Else
    'Uncheck the checkbox
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = -4146
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `wb` (your workbook) has no property  `wst` - just use the worksheet variable `wst`. Change the line to `wst.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = 1` - and do the same in the `else`-branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're using `ActiveSheet` on one part of the `If Else` block. You could either use it for both parts like this:

```
Sub Check_Method1(cbbln As Boolean)
  If cbbln = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = 1
  Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = -4146
  End If
End Sub
```

Or you could use this to make your code safer:

```
Sub Check_Method1(cbbln As Boolean)
    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Set wst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

  If cbbln = True Then
    wst.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = 1
  Else
    wst.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = -4146
  End If
End Sub
```

Either way you don't need to set a workbook you're only using the `Worksheet` which you set using `ThisWorkbook`

---

But you could actually just use this one-liner:

```
Sub Check_Method1(cbbln As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = cbbln
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I try the last code, but it works wrong... with same sessage. Can I send or insert the file?

Comment: If none of these work then you're assigning your CheckBox wrong, it's probably not a Shape, it might be an ActiveX control. How did you insert the CheckBox?

Comment: Really, it is an ActiveX controll.

Comment: OK, it is working! Great! Now i have to transfer this value to a word checkboxs from the excel. How can I do it? What are you offering?

Comment: You would have to ask another specific question on StackOverflow. You're supposed to mark answers that helped you as correct, to give points too. This site works on recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You already set "wst" as a worksheet of "wb":

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

So, you should only do:

```
wst.Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = 1
```